# Why won't pip install the current version of a package?

Tags: python, pip, package, pydot

I can't get `pip` to install the current version of `pydot` (1.0.28). Though `yolk` and [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydot/) both report this version as the available, current one,

`pip -U pydot`

gives me

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pydot in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: pyparsing in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pydot)
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pydot)
```

forcing the current version with

`pip -U pydot==1.0.28`

gives me

```
Downloading/unpacking pydot==1.0.28
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pydot==1.0.28 (from versions: 1.0.2)
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for pydot==1.0.28
```

and even

`pip -U --allow-external pydot pydot==1.0.28`

gives me

```
Downloading/unpacking pydot==1.0.28
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pydot==1.0.28 (from versions: 1.0.2)
  Some insecure and unverifiable files were ignored (use --allow-unverified pydot to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for pydot==1.0.28
```

Comment: What about `--allow-external` option?

Comment: It might look like pydot is hosted externally - as pip says.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951748/pydot-and-graphviz-error-couldnt-import-dot-parser-loading-of-dot-files-will

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`pip install --allow-unverified pydot pydot==1.0.28`