# how to append 2 graphs (graph1 and graph2) using pydot in python

Tags: python, pydot

I generate a pydot graph with the following code

`graph1 = pydot.Dot(graph_type='digraph')
A = pydot.Node("A", style="filled", fillcolor="green")
B = pydot.Node("B", style="filled", fillcolor="blue")
graph1.add_node(A)
graph1.add_node(B)
graph1.add_edge(pydot.Edge(A,B))
graph1.write_png('graph1.png')`

and my output is

[image: graph1]

and I generate a another pydot graph with the following code

```
graph2 = pydot.Dot(graph_type='digraph')
C = pydot.Node("C", style="filled", fillcolor="green")
D = pydot.Node("D", style="filled", fillcolor="blue")
graph2.add_node(C)
graph2.add_node(D)
graph2.add_edge(pydot.Edge(C,D))
graph2.write_png('graph2.png')
```

and my output is as follows.

[image: graph2]

My request is how to merge these 2 graphs(graph1 and graph2)?
My expected output after merging as

[image: merged graph]

I tried with the following code, but, its not working..

```
graph3 = pydot.Dot(graph_type='digraph')
graph1_leaf = pydot.Node(graph1.get_node(B), style="filled", 
fillcolor="green")
graph2_root = pydot.Node(graph2.get_node(C), style="filled", 
fillcolor="green")

graph3.add_node(graph1_leaf)
graph3.add_node(graph2_root)
graph3.add_edge(pydot.Edge(graph1_leaf,graph2_root))
graph3.write_png('graph3.png')
```

Please guide me to merge these 2 graphs using pydot in python.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find documentation describing joining 2 graphs. the common practice seems to be joining 2 sub graphs (clusters).

Here is answer that shows how it's done:
[Edges between two subgraphs in pydot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953957/edges-between-two-subgraphs-in-pydot)

another helpful answer:
[Merge two dot graphs at a common node in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041494/merge-two-dot-graphs-at-a-common-node-in-python)

## Update, answer for edited question:

a few issues with your code:

1. graph1.get_node(B) returns a list of nodes
2. you are adding only the nodes and edge for connecting the graphs while you want all other nodes and edges

This code should return your wanted result:

```
graph3 = pydot.Dot(graph_type='digraph')
for node in graph1.get_nodes():
    graph3.add_node(node)
for node in graph2.get_nodes():
    graph3.add_node(node)
for edge in graph1.get_edges():
    graph3.add_edge(edge)
for edge in graph2.get_edges():
    graph3.add_edge(edge)
node_graph1 = graph1.get_node('B')[0]    
node_graph2 = graph2.get_node('C')[0]
graph3.add_edge(pydot.Edge(node_graph1,node_graph2))

graph3.write_png('/tmp/graph3.png')
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. based on your comment I modified my question.. Please go through my modified question and guide me.. Thanks..

Comment: Your code perfectly working what I expected.. Thank you very much sir..